PC Crashes - Drivers? CPU? GPU?
After much testing and advice, I have a recurring issue that I cannot figure out.
Current setup (Recently built)
CPU: Ryzen 7 5700X
MB: Gigabyte B550M
RAM: 32 GB XPG Spectra D35
GPU: Radeon RX 6600
SSD: 2 Samsung 860 EVOs (512 and 1 TB, respectively)
PSU: CoolerMaster Masterwatt 750 (3.5 years old)
OS: Windows 11 Pro
What's Happening
I experience persistent crashes, complete reboots. Mostly while playing games, but occasionally while using the PC normally. Temps for CPU & GPU remain between 30-60C.
I can replicate the problem by going to Device Manager>Display Adaptors>GPU>Properties>Driver>Driver Details
Whenever I  click on Driver Details, 4 out of 5 times, the computer hard crashes. In Windows Event Viewer, this is the error that preceded the crash, with the more detailed view to follow:

A fatal hardware error has occurred.
Reported by component: Processor Core Error Source: Machine Check
Exception Error Type: Bus/Interconnect Error Processor APIC ID: 0
The details view of this entry contains further information.

What I Have Tried
BIOS: Updated to newest version, FEe — Reset CMOS
OS: Reinstalled Windows in offline mode and installed all drivers
GPU: Uninstalled and installed drivers with DDU multiple times, in offline mode — Used Eco mode — Undervolted — Rolled back drivers — Used my old card (Rx 570) — Limited FPS to 60 — Reseated GPU — Stress tested with OCCT for 10 minutes
PSU: Replaced cable going to GPU (modular)
CPU: Reseated (no bent pins) — installed updated drivers in offline mode
RAM: Reseated — Ran WMD with no issues found
SSD: Ran Samsung Magician with no issues found
Does this seem like a case of a bad driver? GPU? Or... a CPU?
XML from Event Viewer:
- System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-WHEA-Logger 
   [ Guid]  {c26c4f3c-3f66-4e99-8f8a-39405cfed220} 
 
   EventID 18 
 
   Version 0 
 
   Level 2 
 
   Task 0 
 
   Opcode 0 
 
   Keywords 0x8000000000000000 
 
  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2024-12-26T23:11:44.0295307Z 
 
   EventRecordID 4226 
 
  - Correlation 

   [ ActivityID]  {5041b803-036c-4f62-8d38-a90218cb9338} 
 
  - Execution 

   [ ProcessID]  4024 
   [ ThreadID]  4328 
 
   Channel System 
 
   Computer DESKTOP-H0CLQ2G 
 
  - Security 

   [ UserID]  S-1-5-19 
 

- EventData 

  ErrorSource 3 
  ApicId 0 
  MCABank 27 
  MciStat 0xfaa000000000080b 
  MciAddr 0x0 
  MciMisc 0xd0130fff00000000 
  ErrorType 10 
  TransactionType 256 
  Participation 0 
  RequestType 0 
  MemorIO 2 
  MemHierarchyLvl 3 
  Timeout 0 
  OperationType 256 
  Channel 256 
  Length 2063 
  RawData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


What was the recent upgrade? Did it work or still have problems with the old graphics card? Have you tried a different PCIe slot for the graphics card?

Really, it was more recently built. The only thing that was taken over (new MB, CPU, RAM, GPU) was the case, PSU and SSDs, but they were wiped. And it’s a micro ATX board, so only one PCIe, sadly. Thanks!

Did it work or still have problems with the RX 570 graphics card?

I tried to install the 570, but the system crashed while installing the drivers, and began to act odd. Thus, I assumed it was something else.

WinDBG can be used to analyze the system dump

Ah, if it's got only one PCIe slot then it's a mini ATX board. Yes, micro is bigger than mini when it comes to ATX motherboard sizes.

Always get those boards confused :) And I tried to install the 570 again, drivers installed correctly, erasing the old in Safe Mode. But, everything is happening just as before - no change, sadly. And for the life of me, I cannot find the system dumps - is it possible that Windows doesn't have time to generate one? And lastly, I'll update the original post with the XML from Event Viewer. Thank you all!

If a BSOD is displayed then a memory dump was created.

No BSOD was displayed, just an immediate reboot. I’ll click on Driver Details, cursor will spin, then black screen and full reboot. Same thing in games.


You could try running Ubuntu off a USB drive and looking to see if there is an equivalent to the "Driver Details" that fairly reliably crashes the computer. However...


... 2) Is there a computer repair shop near you who would swap out the CPU for you as a test? "Bus/Interconnect Error Processor" means it's either the CPU or the motherboard that has a problem - I was a bit hopeful that it would "only" be the graphics card.
